# How can I add parentheses as the highest level of precedence in a simple grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, parentheses, operator-precedence

I'm trying to add 2 things to my grammar:

1. Unary minus sign, i.e. '-', and
2. Parentheses

Here's my grammar so far:

```
<comp>  ::= <expr> | <comp> <op0> <expr>
<expr>  ::= <term> | <expr> <op1> <term>
<term>  ::= <darg> | <term> <op2> <darg>
<darg>  ::= <digit> | <darg> <digit>
<digit> ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
<op0>   ::= > | < | =< | => | =
<op1>   ::= + | -
<op2>   ::= * | /
```

I've tried everything and can't figure this out. How can I make the unary minus sign be at the highest level of precedence, followed by parentheses next and then the remaining operators as they are described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding a new variable named `<new>` *with three new production rules* in your present grammar in question to add `Unary minus sign` and  `Parentheses`:

```
<comp>  ::= <expr>   | <comp> <op0> <expr>
<expr>  ::= <term>   | <expr> <op1> <term>
<term>  ::= <new>    | <term> <op2> <darg>
<new>   ::= (<comp>) | -<darg> | <darg> 
<darg>  ::= <digit>  |  <darg> <digit>
<digit> ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
<op0>   ::= > | < | =< | => | =
<op1>   ::= + | -
<op2>   ::= * | /
```

<sub>by adding  Parentheses, you are adding tow new terminals in your grammar `{ (, ) }`</sub>

Also, you can add `<new>   ::= ( <new> )` if you want to generate `(-7)`, `(7)` and `((6+7))` like expressions.(*these are valid expressions*)

<sub>I would like to inform you that if you are writing compiler, use ambiguous grammar instead and add operator precedence in YACC tool that will allow efficient parsing</sub>

**EDIT**:

If you wants to add expression like `-(7)` and that is a valid expression. So `<new> ::= -<new>` instead of `<new> ::= <drag>`

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand why I added new variable. I hope it would helpful

Comment: I wasn't sure where to place my new non-terminal. What you did makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the second alternative for `<new>` be `-<new>` so that a parenthesized expression can be negated?

Comment: @ebohlman Yes, if you wants to add expression like `-(7)` and that is a valid expression. So `<new> ::= -<new>` instead of `<new> ::= <drag>` that good

Answer (score 2):

Change `<term>` to use `<fred>` instead of `<darg>` and define

```
<fred> ::= -<fred> | (<comp>) | <darg>
```